# Probability that a closed figure formed by n points on circumference of a circle overlap with centre of circle

Tags: probability-theory

Take a circle with centre $O$.
Let's draw $n$ points on the circumference of the circle.
Let's join the points and create a polygon.
Can we tell that for n points there will be a specific formula for probability that point $O$ is present inside the polygon formed?

Comment: A particular case is very nicely covered (in a way which generalizes easily) here: https://youtu.be/OkmNXy7er84

Comment: (Actually in the link above the 3D case is also studied.)

Comment: logic tag seems inappropriate

Comment: We are assuming that the points are joined in order around the circle to form a simple polygon (no self-intersections)? To put it another way, we are taking the convex hull of the points?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Yes Gerry that is correct

Answer (score 0):

The $n$ points will contain $O$ if and only if they do not all lie on a semicircle. Let's parameterize the points by their angle $\theta$, with the understanding that the parameter is $\theta$ if the point is at coordinate $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. If all points lie on a semicircle, you can find one point $\theta$ such that the other points are in $[\theta, \theta+\pi)$ (mod $2\pi$). The probability that $n-1$ points are in $[\theta, \theta+\pi)$ is $0.5^{n-1}$ and there are $n$ ways of picking the first point. Therefore, the probability that all points are on a semicircle is $n 0.5^{n-1}$, and the requested probability is $1 -n 0.5^{n-1}$.